# Stationarity and Chow-Lin disaggregation

Tags: time-series, stationarity, frequency, disaggregation

My goal is to have higher frequency data (quarterly) for the GDP of my region (yearly data) through quarterly auxiliary data. Therefore my goal is to perform a Chow-Lin regression using the package `tempdisagg` in R Studio. The time series are not stationary.

My question is: do I have to render the time series stationary (es. through differencing) before applying the disaggregation? I've searched online and the literature reports that the Chow-Lin methodology is suited only for stationary data. However, I have read about a lot of exaples in which the procedure seems to be applied directly on raw data:

- https://cros-legacy.ec.europa.eu/system/files/Macro-Integration-06-M-Chow-Lin%20v1.0.pdf
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tempdisagg/vignettes/intro.html